# Elements loaded via ajax can't be used in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I tried to put my data tables in another file and load that via ajax, sadly the form submission doesn't work anymore.

I just get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: this.type is undefined**, the idRow Value is still submitted (I can print that to console) so at the moment I don't get why it says that it is undefined.

When all was in a single page the following was working without Problems:

Form creation and submission after button click:

```
<script>
        function submitForm(rowid) {
            form = document.createElement("form");
            form.action = "save_tables.php"; /
            form.method = "post"; 
            form.style.display = "none";
            $("#"+rowid+" td").children().each(function() { 
                if(this.type.substring(0,6) == "select") { 
                    input = document.createElement("input"); 
                    input.name = this.name;
                    input.type = "hidden";
                    input.value = this.value;
                    form.appendChild(input);
                } else {
                    $(this).clone().appendTo(form);
                }

            });
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
</script>
```

Example for one entry in the table

```
<tr id="entry_4" class="row100 body">
<td><input type="text" name="lang"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="l_code"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code"/></td>
<td><button onclick="submitForm('entry_4')">Change</button></td>
</tr>
```

I replaced the table with the following and then loaded the tables via ajax.

```
<div align="center" id="selection">
<button onclick="showTables('lang')">Lang</button>
<button onclick="showTables('cat')">Cat</button>
</div>

<div id="target">
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function showTables(showtype) {
        $.get(`load_tables.php?show=${showtype}`, function(data) {
            $('#target').html(data);
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Off-topic: `$("#target").load(\`load_tables.php?show=${showtype}\`)` would do the same as the `$.get()` call in `showTables()`

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and "vanilla" JS? Why doesn't `submitForm()` use `$.ajax()` instead of that manually crafted `<form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and a fix, even though I don't know why it happens.

When loading the table via ajax, this.type is undefined for some inputs so I changed the
`if(this.type.substring(0,6) == "select") {`

to the following to get it working:

`if(typeof this.type != 'undefined' && this.type.substring(0,6) == "select") {`

All inputs are submitted (even if there is a select one) so it works for me